# How to code this java program? I know how to code in interval but with only one inputted and then sum of 2 prime is equivalent to inputted number

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the question: " Prepare a java program that will accept a non-negative even number (higher than 2) and extract the two prime numbers when add, the sum is equivalent to users input non-negative even number.

Sample output.

```
"Enter Number: 20" 
"17 & 3" or "3 & 17"
```

I tried to code the prime number in between two inputted number. but i dont know how to code the question above. :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrimeNumberInInterval{ 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int n1, n2, i, j, pn; 
        System.out.println("Starting number: "); 
        n1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ending number: "); 
        n2 = input.nextInt();
  
        System.out.println("The prime numbers in between are: "+n1 + n2); 
     
        for (i = n1; i <= n2; i++) { 
            if (i == 1 || i == 0) 
                continue; 
            pn = 1; 
            for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; ++j) { 
                if (i % j == 0) { 
                    pn = 0; 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
            if (pn == 1) 
                System.out.println(i); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: HINT: start by making a method `boolean isPrime(int n)` that can tell you if a given number is prime.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a starting and ending number. Just, given a number n, such that n is even and n >= 2, find two primes such that p1 + p2 = n. For n = 2, the two primes are both 1. I don't know about other numbers.

Comment: BTW: We are not a homework-writing service, but we are here to help you when you find a specific problem with your code.

Comment: Please post a specific question about a specific coding problem. thx

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical terms, this problem is called [Goldbach's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) where every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as sum of two primes.
Now, one approach to solve this problem involves doing 2 things:

1. Generate all prime numbers smaller than `2 * n + 2` where `n` is the given number. This generation of prime numbers can be easily done by using [Sieve of Sundaram algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram)
2. Once you have generated the prime numbers, start subtracting each prime number from the given number n and check if the difference is also a prime number or not. If yes, then you have found your result.

A simple implementation of Sieve of Sundaram algorithm can be done using a `boolean` array and a `List` of integers:

```
List<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    public void generatePrimes(int n) {
        // As we want prime numbers smaller than n,
        // reduce n to half (calling this as nHalf)
        int nHalf = (n - 1) / 2;

        // This marker is used to mark the numbers which are of the form i + j + 2*i*j
        // from the rest where 1 <= i <= j as per Sieve of Sundaram algorithm
        boolean[] marker = new boolean[nHalf + 1];

        // Mark all numbers of the form i + j + 2*i*j
        for(int i = 1; i <= nHalf; i++) {
            for(int j = i; (i + j + 2 * i * j) <= nHalf; j++) {
                marker[i + j + 2 * i * j] = false;
            }
        }
        // Add 2 as it is a prime number
        primeNumbers.add(2);

    // Once all the numbers of the form i + j + 2*i*j are marked, remaining numbers should be
    // doubled and incremented by 1 to get odd prime numbers
        for(int i = 1; i <= nHalf; i++) {
            if(marker[i] == false) {
                primeNumbers.add(2 * i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, getting the prime numbers for the given number `num` is as simple as:

```
generatePrimes(num);
        for(int i = 0; primeNumbers.get(i) <= num/2; i++) {
            // find difference by subtracting current prime number from given number num
            int difference = num - primeNumbers.get(i);

            // Check if difference is also a prime number.
            if(primeNumbers.contains(difference)) {
                System.out.println(primeNumbers.get(i) + " AND " + difference);
                break;
            }
        }
```